# Is there a way to reduce cpu & memory usage of flash in web browser?

Tags: flash

I'm playing web-based flash game. The flash game consumes a lot of memory and cpu usage. But when I minimum the web browser, is there any setting to let flash keep running but release some memory and cpu since it needs not to rendering due to invisible.

If the setting is not available on web browsers, e.g. IE, firefox, is it possible to build my own MFC based application that embeds a IE control with some special settings?

Comment: Run the 32-bit version of the browser, that will often cut your memory consumption in half.

Comment: Some addon may help you https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/low-quality-flash/

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a solution, but you'll have to use it on your own risk:

To reduce the memory footprint you can use [Firemin](http://www.neowin.net/news/firemin-20111---optimize-firefox-memory-usage) which frees up allocated but unused memory of Firefox. This should also work for flash content. It's reliable and stable.

To reduce CPU load you have to use a tool that allows you to pause processes like [PsSuspend](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx).

Another way would be to run the browser and the app in a virtual machine. Then you can pause and suspend it at will freeing all memory and CPU time from the flash app, but the total overhead running this setup will be a lot bigger.

You could also use a non-browser environment that supports flash such as Media Player Classic. I played a couple of flash games with it. This way you save the massive overhead the browser itself requires, but not all flash games might be supported or run flawlessly. Then again, there are probably a ton of different non-browser application that should allow you to run your game, so this might be the best solution of all.

Answer (score 0):

I see no feasible way of reducing a currently running Flash application memory footprint. Even if you minimize your browser and the application goes idle (although I'm pretty sure it doesn't), you would ease the load off the CPU, but not off the memory. The state of the application must be stored the way it is, because otherwise it wouldn't be able to function correctly.

Certainly some problems in the platform or bugs in the application may lead to some memory leaking, i.e., becoming unreachable by code but still occupied by data. But this is a problem that needs to be addressed by the platform's [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). And doing garbage collection right is a pretty complicated task.

The only way to make the application use less memory is not letting it use more of it in the first place. "Sandbox" (I don't know how) the app and force it to stay in a certain memory quota - this way you will be sure that it won't use any more memory that it is allowed.

Answer (score -1):

One of the inherent problems with Flash is that it was never intended to be used the way it is. Each instance of a Flash program is treated as if it is the only flash code running, and each flash script/program is allowed to use 10% of your memory. Some web sites see this as a good thing, as they can use it to keep you from surfing multiple sites or having multiple accounts accessed at once. Using facebook as an example, the page is sorted using flash script, the header with the menus at the top is another script, each block to the left may be one script or several scripts running in a separate script, the same goes for the right, and fore each post. So, depending on how it parses out, each facebook page is running between 4 and an undefined number of scripts.

Comment: That's an interesting explanation of the underlying problem, but it doesn't explain how to solve what was asked in the question.